# Apply window function over multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to perform window function (concretely moving average), but over all columns of a dataframe.

I can do it this way

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as func

df = ...

df.select([func.avg(df[col]).over(windowSpec).alias(col) for col in df.columns])
```

but I'm afraid this isn't very efficient. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: seems good to me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but isn't this inefficient as this is window operation? Will Spark partition and sort the data for each column, one by one, or will it do it only once and calculate the rolling average for all columns in parallel?

Comment: I would hate having something like `[partition,sort,calculate_avg(column) for column in columns]`,if that makes sense.

Comment: You could look at the `DAG` to see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, where I have a few hundred columns and basically want to do a "fillin" type of operation - for each column, for each row if the value is missing, pick it up from the last existing one. Did you manage to optimize this in any way?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative which may be better is to create a new df where you Group By the columns in Window function and apply average on the remaining columns then do a left join. For large data frames where the df is being spilled over to disk (or cannot be persisted in memory), this will definitely be more optimal.

Comment: In the above case would window functions spill the df over to disk? I can't see how if the groupby columns are the same as what the df is partitioned by already