# apply window function to multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF with over 20 columns. For each column I need to find the lead value and add it to the result.

I've been doing it using with column.

```
df
.withColumn("lead_col1", lead("col1").over(window))
.withColumn("lead_col2", lead("col2").over(window))
.withColumn("lead_col3", lead("col3").over(window))
```

and 17 more rows like that. Is there a way to do it using less code? I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545864/apply-window-function-over-multiple-columns) exampe, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are using scala, you can have list columns and use foldleft to add columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code, it is faster than `foldLeft`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val windowSpec = ...
val windowColumns = Seq(
                         ("lead_col1", "col1"),
                         ("lead_col2","col2"),
                         ("lead_col3","col3")
                    ).map(c => lead(col(c._2),1).over(windowSpec).as(c._1))

val windowColumns = df.columns ++ windowColumns
```

Applying `windowColumns` to DataFrame.

```
df.select(windowColumns:_*).show(false)
```

Comment: The example is interestig, but it doesn't work. Or rather, the select only works with the first `windowColumns`. Which only has half needed columns. Also the execution plan is generaly the same but has 2 additional steps `+- *Project [col1#0... ]`. Why do you think it should work faster?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487649/how-can-i-add-multiple-columns-in-spark-datframe-in-efficiently/62487899#62487899 for performance comparison..I have added code as an example..

Comment: And also this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63026858/how-to-efficiently-map-over-df-and-use-combination-of-outputs/63027144#63027144 .. foldleft is slower that select function

Answer (score 0):

Like Sath suggested, foldleft works.

```
  val columns = df.columns
  columns.foldLeft(df){(tempDF, colName) =>
    tempDF.withColumn("lag_" + colName, lag($"$colName", 1).over(window))}
```